# How to run parallel instances of a Luigi Pipeline : Pid set already running

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pipeline, luigi

I have a simple pipeline.

I want to start it once with the Id 2381, then while the first job is running I want to start a second run with the Id 231. The first run completes as expected.

The second run returns this response

```
Pid(s) set([10362]) already running
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am starting the runs like this

run one:

```
luigi.run(
    cmdline_args=["--id='newId13822'", "--TaskTwo-id=2381"],
    main_task_cls=TaskTwo()
)
```

run two:

```
luigi.run(
    cmdline_args=["--id='newId1322'", "--TaskTwo-id=231"],
    main_task_cls=TaskTwo()
)
```

The tasks each have a unique ID as generated by luigi's task_id_str(...) method. Why does luigi think that the task is already running when the luigi.paramater, TaskTwo-id and MockTarget files are all different?

Pipeline code:

```
import time
import uuid
from luigi.mock import MockTarget
import luigi


class TaskOne(luigi.Task):
    run_id = luigi.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        return MockTarget("TaskOne{0}".format(self.run_id), mirror_on_stderr=True)

    def run(self):
        _out = self.output().open('w')
        time.sleep(10)
        _out.write(u"Hello World!\n")
        _out.close()


class TaskTwo(luigi.Task):
    id = luigi.Parameter(default=uuid.uuid4().__str__())

    def output(self):
        return MockTarget("TaskTwo{0}".format(self.id), mirror_on_stderr=True)

    def requires(self):
        return TaskOne(self.id)

    def run(self):
        _out = self.output().open('w')
        time.sleep(10)
        _out.write(u"Hello World!\n")
        _out.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this might be because you are not connecting to a scheduler server, so it is trying to start a scheduler process twice. Are you running luigid?

I was able to get your code to run at the command line as follows. First I created a dir and dropped your code in a file called luigitest.py (minus the luigi.run() commands). I changed directory into the directory I created. Then I ran:

```
luigid --background --pidfile ./luigid.pid --logdir . --state-path .
```

Then I opened up a second terminal in the same directory. In the first one I ran:

```
PYTHONPATH=. luigi --module luigitest TaskOne --run-id newId13822 --TaskTwo-id 2381 --local-scheduler
```

In the second one I ran (about a second later):

```
PYTHONPATH=. luigi --module luigitest TaskOne --run-id newId13823 --TaskTwo-id 2382 --local-scheduler
```

These both output "Hello World!"

Comment: luigid is running.

Comment: Ah, then it looks like you are not connecting to it. I edited the answer to show a standard way of connecting to a local scheduler.

Comment: I also had trouble with this. In my case, the tasks were running with different parameters, but these were defined in a configuration file (passed via the LUIGI_CONFIG_PATH) rather than passed via the command line. Somehow this resulted in the two tasks getting the same PID, whereas explicitly passing a different parameter allowed them to run simultaneously.

Comment: @MattMcKnight if `--local-scheduler` is specified, `luigid` is not used, right?

Comment: @Javier I think when there is --local-scheduler, the worker will not check the scheduler for new tasks. Haven't used it for a while though!